# Tabbar like effect with Jquery

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, tabbar

I want to create a tab bar like portion on the base of the app view just like in iPhone.I want it to be designed in jQuery and html on android phone gap app.Is there framework or samples for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/CKvYv/

Are you looking for something like this??

Check this out for [andriod tab](http://code.google.com/p/androidtabs/)